# Does Nutch 2.1 still support file segments?

Tags: nutch

Does Nutch 2.1 still support file segments as the data storage?

I cannot find my answer from the documentation or wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the nutch segments which had part files ? According to me, Nutch 2.0 does NOT have that.